# Why is Ionic 4 returning a 404 from a POST request?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Latest version of Ionic CLI: 5.4.2

I've tested my `POST` endpoint in Postman and it's working as it should. I can also do `GET` requests from inside my Ionic app, I just can't do `POST` requests.

I've installed the Cordova whitelist plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova prepare
```

I've added the following (with my real url) in `config.xml`

```html
<access origin="http://api.example.test" />
<allow-intent href="http://api.example.test/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://api.example.test/*" />
```

I've added the following to `index.html`

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' data:; img-src * data:; default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' * ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

I've removed the whitelist plugin and reinstalled it. Nothing is working; I just keep getting 404 errors when testing in Chrome.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's looks like CORS Origin issue. Please installed chrome extension for CORS request

Comment: beacuse of your api url not found

Comment: @PareshGami That did't fix it either.